# Insert tokens where TeX would put a linebreak?

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx

Given a TeX paragraph, is there any way to insert tokens at places where TeX would automatically insert line breaks (similar to \everypar?)

To give some context, I am writing a LaTeX package for typesetting programming language syntax. Given something like

```
\begin{format}
  Types \alpha ::= \tau | \tau \to \tau | \mu \alpha. \tau | ...
\end{format}
```

It should be converted to a tabularx with columns for "Types", "\alpha", "::=", and the body of the definition (specification X). The X column is defined such that its contexts are typeset in mathmode and | is redefined to \mid. However, if the line is too long, it should wrap, and the | should appear where the ::= appeared. For example,

```
Types \alpha ::= \tau | \tau \to \tau
              |  \mu \alpha. \tau
```

My tentative strategy is to insert an appropriate "\ \multicolumn{...}" sequence of tokens before every TeX linebreak, such that I can insert the | in the place where the ::= went.

Any ideas?

(P.S., I don't think existing BNF packages for LaTeX can do this -- the ones I've seen require an explicit command for breaking the line and putting the | where the ::= went.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make it ragged right and then tell TeX that the | is a good place to break a line by playing around with values to `\penalty`. Depending on how you're convincing TeX that | should be replaced by `\mid`, you could do this with something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\mathcode`|="8000
\begingroup
\catcode`|\active
\gdef|{\penalty2000\mid\nobreak}
\endgroup
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
$AAAAAAAAAA|BBBBBBBBBBB|CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC|DDDDDDDDDDDDD
|EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE|FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF|GGGGGGGGGGGGGG|HHHHHHHHHHHHH$
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Here's a more complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colonequals}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`|\active
\gdef\setupformatpipe{%
        \mathcode`\|="8000
        \catcode`\|\active
        \def|{\penalty-1\makebox[\widthof{$\m@th{}\coloncolonequals{}$}]{$\m@th\mid$}\nobreak}%
}
\endgroup

\newenvironment{format}
        {\setupformatpipe
         \tabularx{\linewidth}{lr@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
        {\endtabularx}
\def\formatrow#1 #2::=#3\\{%
        #1&$\m@th#2$&$\m@th{}\coloncolonequals#3$\\
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{format}
\formatrow Types \alpha ::= \tau | \tau \to \tau | \mu \alpha. \tau |
AAAAAAAAAAAAA | BBBBBBBBBBBB | CCCCCCCCCCC | DDDDDDDDDDDDD
| EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF\\
\formatrow {} \beta ::= GGGGGGGGGGGG | HHHHHHHHHHHHHH |
IIIIIIIIIIIIIII | JJJJJJJJJJJJ | KKKKKKKKKKK | LLLLLLL\\
\end{format}
\end{document}
```

It does require the use of that `\formatrow` macro though.

Comment: But how do I know which |'s TeX decided to break at, so that I can insert extra tokens (the \multicolumn stuff) at that point?

Comment: @Christopher: Oh sorry, I omitted part of what I meant to say. I wouldn't use a `\multicolumn` there. Let me see if I can hack something up.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're doing. The problem is that the | doesn't precisely line up in the center with the ::= and the item following doesn't line up with the first item. i.e., if BBBBBBBB was the first item on a new line, it should line up with \tau. The \multicolumn trick would get around this, if it was possible.

Comment: @Christopher: Yeah, that was just a mistake. It's fixed now. (I forgot the `{}` before and after the `\coloncolonequals`.)

Answer (score 1):

I would put the ::= so that it is actually (partly) in the third column:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll>{\makebox[0pt]{::=}\quad}p{2cm}}
Types &$\alpha$ & $\tau | \tau \to \tau \allowbreak
              |  \mu \alpha. \tau$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```